# Start rails server on a domain I mapped in my host file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to map:

www.example.com

in  my host file, how can I start 'rails server' so it uses this domain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Edit the hosts file (instructions for OSX Snow Leopard)

1. `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
2. Add a line `127.0.0.1 www.example.com`
3. Refresh DNS settings with `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

## Start rails on the correct port

`rails server` will now work on http://www.example.com:3000/. To get rid of :3000, start Rails with: `sudo rails server --port=80` (or `rvmsudo` if you are using RVM)

For production use, you might want to see Kevins answer.

Comment: i want to do it on a different i.p, not 127.0.0.1. or 0.0.0.0 but maybe 127.0.0.2 (just so it doesn't effect anything else)

Comment: The whole 127.0.0.0/8 block is mapped to local loopback interface (what a waste of precious IPV4 addresses!) so you are free to use whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) on either Nginx or Apache to do this. Doing a quick search on your operating system should come up with a tutorial on how to set everything up correctly.